# Can I compile Dart code from Java/Scala?

Tags: java, scala, jvm, dart

Can I compile Dart to Javascript from a Java Virtual Machine based application?

I'm developing a web application that runs in the JVM. I'm thinking about allowing people to save and compile Dart via my web application, and then that compiled Dart code would be included on certain pages, as Javascript.

I suppose in theory the answer is yes, because it should be possible to somehow bundle the Dart editor or the dart2js program in my JVM application, and make an external process call to Dart. But I'm wondering: Is there any "easy" way to compile Dart, from Java? Like including some JAR and then it'll work? Or calling out to some scripting language via the JVM's script engine?

Answer (score 0):

https://code.google.com/p/jdart/
Is this what you want? It compiles dart into a jar file. I haven't actually used it yet though...

Comment: Thanks, interesting, but no, it's not what I was looking for. The Dart code should be included in a Web page served to web browser, as Javascript. So it's Dart --> Javascript, not --> Java. I think it's an interesting project however, in case one wants to reuse some Dart code snippets server side :-)